# Guice - How to make a class with no args constructor singleton and let the variables auto injected?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have below code sample

```
public interface MyDao {
    ...
}

public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {
    ...
}

public class MyService {
    @Inject
    private MyDao myDao;

    ...
}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(MyDao.class).to(MyDaoImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

In main class, I have

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
MyService myService = injector.getInstance(MyService.class);
MyService myService2 = injector.getInstance(MyService.class);
```

`myService` and `myService2` are different objects.

If I add below code in `MyModule`

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public MyService getMyService() {
    return new MyService();
}
```

`myService` and `myService2` become same object, but the variable `myDao` becomes null.

How can I make `MyService` singleton and let the variable `myDao` auto injected without changing the constructor of `MyService`?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid changing the constructor? It's best practice and makes life simpler in a number of ways.

Comment: @chrylis Agree changing the constructor makes life easier, but in Spring the variables can be auto injected in a non-parameter constructor class.

Comment: They can be, and it's strongly recommended against (and considered a design mistake by the author).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you gave, you are generating the `MyService` by simply calling its constructor, rather than injection.

To solve your problem, you can bind your service in the configuration and create it with the call to `getInstance`

```
public class MyModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(MyDao.class).to(MyDaoImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(MyService.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

Note that, as stated by [chrylis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis), it would be a better solution to change the constructor or add a setter for your `MyDao` object in the `MyService` class. If you ever have to create your object without injection or even have to change injection framework, that would save you an incommensurable amount of time.

Comment: Agree changing the constructor makes life easier, but in Spring the variables can be auto injected in a non-parameter constructor class.

Comment: @coderz, yes in spring, as in guice, variables can be injected in a non-parameter constructor class. But though spring and guice are the main injection frameworks, they are not the only ones. And anyway, the absence of parameters in the constructor (or setter) makes the code dependent on the use of an injection framework.